# Regex to capture named groups in any order

Tags: python, regex

I have a scenario in which I need to use a single call to Python's re.sub() to find and replace items in a string.  If that constraint sounds contrived, just consider this a mental exercise, but know that it is a real-life constraint I have to work with.

I want to match and replace a line like either of these:

```
foo -some-arg -o %output %input
foo %input -other-random-arg=baz -o %output
```

with this:

```
bar %output %input.out
```

The file names %input and %output can be anything matching `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+` but are always preceded by `%`

I came up with this substitution which does not quite work.

```
    r'''(?x)                     # Begin verbose regex
        foo[ ]                   # foo and a space
        (?=.*?-o[ ]                  # Lookahead for the first occurrence of -o
            (?P<a>%\S+\b)                # Output filename -> Group 'a'
        )
        (?=.*?                       # Lookahead from the same place as the first lookahead
                                     # so the two filenames can match in any order.
            (?!-o[ ]%\S+\b)              # Do not match the output file
            (?P<b>%\S+\b)                # Any filename -> Group 'b'
        ).*                      # Match anything ''',
    r'bar \g<b> \g<a>.out'       # Replacement
```

I often end up with one of the two file names repeated twice like:

```
bar %output %output.out
```

Is there a way to named-capture the two file names in whatever order they appear?  It seems that if I could advance the regex engine's pointer upon matching the one of the lookaheads, I could make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all arguments begin with a dash and since input and output are always present one time, you can use this kind of pattern that ignores the order:

```
foo(?: -o (?P<output>\S+)| -\S+| (?P<input>\S+))+
```

and the replacement

```
bar \1 \2.out
```

Note: if you want to deal with filenames that contain spaces (that are escaped in a command line), you need to change `\S+` to `(?:[^\s\\]+(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)*|[^\s\\]*(?:\\.[^\s\\]*)+)` *(only for input and output)*

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks!  The group naming isn't even necessary now (though maybe it never was).